# UnicodeDecodeError during pip installation on linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

On Red Hat 4.8  with python 2.7.5 during installation pip 9.0.1 with command
**pip install --upgrade pip**
I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 272, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 594, in __init__
    if include_lsb else {}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 922, in _get_lsb_release_info
    stdout, stderr = stdout.decode('utf-8'), stderr.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 22: invalid continuation byte
```

Some commands of pip work as they should, for example, **pip list** shows the information, but
in the end it also shows traceback as above.

**pip install pandas** doesn't work at all.

**pip --version** command shows:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Also I cannot install the previous version with command:

```
pip install pip=8.1.1
```

Does this mean that installation failed or I need just 
make some changes to make pip work properly?
(By the way all locales are cp1251)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to change the default encoding of your systems,
this code allow you to change it to 'ISO-8859-1':

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: Does this code changes any settings on linux or it only changes python settings?

Comment: You can get the encoding by : `sys.stdin.encoding` in Python terminal

Comment: Or in Linux by `echo $LANG`

Comment: I tried this code: import pip; pip.main(['install', 'pandas']); and the error is the same